# Kilometers (or other value) redistribution algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I would like to know if there is an algorithm for solving kilometers redistribution problems, take for example the path of a taxi:

at start I take Bart
at km 2 I take Homer
at km 5 I take Lenny and Carl
at km 7 I take Barney
at km 10 we arrived at the destination

```
    Bart   |----------| 10km
    Homer    |--------| 8km
    Lenny       |-----| 5Km
    Carl        |-----| 5Km
    Barney        |---| 3Km
```

The result should look something like this:

**EDIT:** 
the correct result is in [Nico Schertler](/users/1210053/nico-schertler)'s [answer](/a/20143933/2853911).

<del>Barney   : **3km / 5 = 0.6 km**</del>
<del>Carl     : **3km / 5 + 5km / 4 = 1.4 km**</del> 
<del>Lenny    : **3km / 5 + 5km / 4 = 1.4 km**</del>
<del>Homer    : **3km / 5 + 5km / 4 + 3 km / 2 = 2.2 km**</del>
<del>Bart     : **3km / 5 + 5km / 4 + 3 km / 2 + 2km = 4.2 km**</del>

<del>0.6 km + 1.4 km + 1.4 km + 2.2 km + 4.2 km = 10 km</del>

even better if I get a rounded result, something like this:

`1 km + 1 km + 1 km + 2 km + 5 km + = 10 km`

Any idea?

Ste

Comment: The algorithm is rather simple, why don't you try doing it yourself?

Comment: Of course! I'm trying, but I accept suggestions.

Comment: @iccthedral At least this is a properly explained question :')

Comment: @Fabinout: I still doesn't see question. *Any idea?* is non-question.

Comment: First of all, what is the question? And secondly, how is problem defined? I can guess it is about "fair" expense sharing, but I don't see "fairness" definition there. And it is still just guess. Most obvious thing for one can be not so obvious at all.

Comment: Well, I guess you're right.

Comment: @Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil: Read the first row!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is not correct

0.6 km + 1.4 km + 1.4 km + 2.2 km + 4.2 km = 9.8 km; not 10!

You probably want something like this:

```
     km |  0-2  |  2-5  |  5-7  |  7-10 | Sum
----------------------------------------------
Bart    | 2 / 1 | 3 / 2 | 2 / 4 | 3 / 5 | 4,6
Omer    |       | 3 / 2 | 2 / 4 | 3 / 5 | 2,6
Lenny   |       |       | 2 / 4 | 3 / 5 | 1,1 
Carl    |       |       | 2 / 4 | 3 / 5 | 1,1
Barney  |       |       |       | 3 / 5 | 0,6
                                         -----
                                         10,0
```

So we can solve the problem starting from the end.

I assume you have a data structure like the following:

```
Person { name, startsAt, partialDistance = 0 }
```

The first step is to sort the list of persons by `startsAt`. And then accumulate the distance:

```
lastCheckPoint = totalDistance
participatingPersons = persons.length
for i from persons.length - 1 to 0
    currentPosition = persons[i].startsAt
    currentDistance = lastCheckPoint - currentPosition
    for j from 0 to i
        persons[j].partialDistance += currentDistance / participatingPersons
    next
    participatingPersons -= 1
    while i >= 1 && persons[i - 1].startsAt == currentPosition
        participatingPersons -= 1
        i -= 1
    loop
    lastCheckpoint = currentPosition
 next
```

This is the basic idea. Distribute the partial distance column by column across the persons.